# Make MongoDB work for production

Tags: mongodb, production-environment

I have made a simple test of MongoDB under windows environment. The single collection of objects with ID (int32) and Buffer (byte[4096]) was filling sequentially. After reaching of almost 15G (of 16G total) RAM, environment becames glitching. Some apps were killed, desktop changed its resolution, then it completely hangs. After hard reboot I've found a lot of such records in mongo log:

VirtualProtect failed (mcw) e:/Databases/+MongoDB/TestFS/TestFS.7 256400000000 4000000 errno:1455 The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.

MapViewOfFile failed e:/Databases/+MongoDB/TestFS/TestFS.26 errno:1450 Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.

Also, MongoDB failed to connect anymore (to any database). Journaling was enabled. No any errors in log. I was able to heal it only by deleting the journal and corrupted database. That's far from the behaviour I'd like to see in production, but I know, that there is a lot of production installations existing. So I'm trying to understand, what have I missed or doing wrong.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?  The [paging error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315270) here should be helpful .. your system likely did not have enough free disk space to extend the paging file (or it was set to a fixed size).

Comment: Thank you. Its possible, because I've tested on the system with swap file disabled.

Comment: Hint: Don't use mongodb for production. (Ours just went down.... again.... Mongo guys know the bug for two years... no fix... https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10044

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this is same question: [MongoDB replication crashes and wouldn't start up again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185958/mongodb-replication-crashes-and-wouldnt-start-up-again)

answers from link:

try to increase your virtual memory 

and this seems like a known bug:  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10044