# MongoDB replication crashes and wouldn't start up again

Tags: windows, mongodb

During insert operations to a MongoDB 2.2.3 shard, running on Windows Server 2008 R2, one of the replications in the shard crashed down with the log files as seen below.

Since the issue seemed to originate from lack of the page-file, I tried doubling its size from 8gb to 15gb but that didn't change my inability to start the replication.

Is it a known bug? Is there a solution?

Please comment if any additional information is required.

**Log during crash**

```
Wed Feb 27 09:02:03 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.159.29:53112 #16840 (14 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:02:21 [conn16839] end connection 192.168.159.26:63150 (13 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:02:21 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.159.26:63153 #16841 (14 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:02:28 [repl writer worker 1] VirtualProtect for E:/MongoDB/data/api.62 chunk 8245 failed with errno:1455 The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. (chunk size is 67108864, address is 80d4000000) in mongo::makeChunkWritable, terminating
Wed Feb 27 09:02:28 [repl writer worker 1]  api.commhistory Fatal Assertion 16362
Wed Feb 27 09:02:33 [conn16840] end connection 192.168.159.29:53112 (13 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:02:33 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.159.29:62053 #16842 (14 connections now open)
```

**I've tried to start it again, however, after 20 seconds or so it crashed again with the following log**

```
Wed Feb 27 09:22:35 [rsBackgroundSync] replSet syncing to: MASB-MGO-MGO01:27017
Wed Feb 27 09:22:35 [rsSync] replSet still syncing, not yet to minValid optime 512dcba3:c
Wed Feb 27 09:22:36 [rsSyncNotifier] replset setting oplog notifier to MASB-MGO-MGO01:27017
Wed Feb 27 09:22:37 [rsHealthPoll] couldn't connect to MASB-MGO-RPL02:27017: couldn't connect to server MASB-MGO-RPL02:27017
Wed Feb 27 09:22:41 [rsHealthPoll] couldn't connect to MASB-MGO-RPL02:27017: couldn't connect to server MASB-MGO-RPL02:27017
Wed Feb 27 09:22:45 [rsHealthPoll] couldn't connect to MASB-MGO-RPL02:27017: couldn't connect to server MASB-MGO-RPL02:27017
Wed Feb 27 09:22:46 [repl writer worker 1] VirtualProtect for E:/MongoDB/data/api.68 chunk 10164 failed with errno:1455 The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. (chunk size is 67108864, address is 9ed0000000) in mongo::makeChunkWritable, terminating
Wed Feb 27 09:22:46 [repl writer worker 1]  api.commhistory Fatal Assertion 16362
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace.cpp(182)                           mongo::printStackTrace+0x3e
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(126)                          mongo::fassertFailed+0x43
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\util\mmap_win.cpp(264)                             mongo::makeChunkWritable+0x342
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\util\mmap.h(274)                                   mongo::MemoryMappedFile::makeWritable+0x56
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\db\dur_commitjob.cpp(93)                           mongo::dur::DurableImpl::declareWriteIntent+0x5f
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\db\dur.cpp(239)                                    mongo::dur::DurableImpl::writingAtOffset+0x18
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\db\btree.cpp(406)                                  mongo::BucketBasics<mongo::BtreeData_V1>::basicInsert+0xcd
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\db\btree.cpp(1309)                                 mongo::BtreeBucket<mongo::BtreeData_V1>::insertHere+0xa0
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\db\index_insertion_continuation.h(66)              mongo::IndexInsertionContinuationImpl<mongo::BtreeData_V1>::doIndexInsertionWrites+0xda
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\db\index_update.cpp(146)                           mongo::indexRecordUsingTwoSteps+0x77a
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\db\pdfile.cpp(1546)                                mongo::DataFileMgr::insert+0x845
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\db\pdfile.cpp(1273)                                mongo::DataFileMgr::insertWithObjMod+0x48
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\db\ops\update.cpp(203)                             mongo::_updateObjects+0x4c2
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\db\oplog.cpp(780)                                  mongo::applyOperation_inlock+0x507
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\db\repl\rs_sync.cpp(84)                            mongo::replset::SyncTail::syncApply+0x245
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\db\repl\rs_sync.cpp(121)                           mongo::replset::multiSyncApply+0x65
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\mongo\util\concurrency\thread_pool.cpp(66)               mongo::threadpool::Worker::loop+0x94
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  ...\src\third_party\boost\libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp(180)  boost::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function+0x21
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(314)      _callthreadstartex+0x17
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] mongod.exe  f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\threadex.c(292)      _threadstartex+0x7f
Wed Feb 27 09:22:48 [repl writer worker 1] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.159.26:64223 #17 (14 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [conn3] end connection 192.168.159.24:5105 (13 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [conn10] end connection 192.168.159.25:51584 (12 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [conn11] end connection 192.168.159.22:50242 (11 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [conn15] end connection 192.168.159.26:64205 (10 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.159.25:51595 #18 (11 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [conn5] end connection 192.168.159.23:54657 (9 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.159.24:5118 #19 (11 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.159.23:54671 #20 (12 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.159.22:50255 #21 (13 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.159.26:64230 #22 (14 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.159.26:64237 #23 (15 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 192.168.159.25:51602 #24 (16 connections now open)
Wed Feb 27 09:23:44 [rsHealthPoll] couldn't connect to MASB-MGO-RPL02:27017: couldn't connect to server MASB-MGO-RPL02:27017
```

**Replication server info**

```
    Operating System
        Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64-bit SP1
    CPU
        Intel Xeon E5 @ 2.60GHz
        Sandy Bridge-EP/EX 32nm Technology
        Intel Xeon E5 @ 2.60GHz
        Sandy Bridge-EP/EX 32nm Technology
        Intel Xeon E5 @ 2.60GHz
        Sandy Bridge-EP/EX 32nm Technology
        Intel Xeon E5 @ 2.60GHz
        Sandy Bridge-EP/EX 32nm Technology
    RAM
        8.00 GB EDO (3-3-3-?)
```

Comment: The interesting part is this: "The paging file is too small for this operation to complete." though Windows should not have this problem.

Comment: Could you please show, what params do you use when you start your mongod?

Comment: @ConstantineNovykov: Here it is `E:\MongoDB\mongod.exe --replSet rs0 --oplogSize 5000 --dbpath E:\MongoDB\data --logpath E:\MongoDB\mongo.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, that it indeed happened due to too-small page-file. Even though increasing it from 8gb to 15gb didn't help, increasing it even more, to 30gb made MongoDB come backup normally.

The fact that MongoDB wouldn't accept DOUBLING the virtual memory size, is still very strange in my eyes.

So... If you have this kind of error, just try to keep increasing your virtual memory and this should help.

Comment: This is actually a known bug with the MongoDB server: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10044 hopefully, it will be resolved soon